# cPanel & Passenger: what's my entry point?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cpanel, passenger

I'm deploying a project on my hosting, but I've some trouble with the 'entry point' of my app.
I've developed an application under react js (with webpack).
When I setup it, I don't know which file to make the '**Application startup file**'?

For the moment, it's a simple 'server.js' that say hello and  give me the current version of node.
When I'm on my project in local, I just launch `npm start` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by editing the 'server.js' file like this :

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
         res.status(500).send(err)
      }
   })
});

app.listen(9000);
```